# JS - Convert nested forloops into single loop

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops, nested, time-complexity

I need to convert this nested loop into a single loop.

This is the loop with the scenario:

- First incrementer is **i** which starts from 0 and should run till 10
- Second incrementer is **j** which starts from **where *i* left off + 1** and runs till 10

.
.

#### My Nested Loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < 10; j++) {

       if (some_condition) {
            do_sth()
       }

    }
}
```

#### My Attempt at conversion

```
var i = 0; 
while (i < 10){
    var j = i + 1;

    if (j < 10) {
        if (some_condition) {
            do_sth()
        }

        j++;
    }

    i++;
}
```

Unfortunately, my attempt doesn't produce the expected results.
The second snippet does not give the output which the first snippet delivers. 
Can anyone please suggest me what my mistake is or provide me a better solution to achieve my target?

Thanks!

Comment: Go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The first nested loop is O(1/2N^2) (or basically N^2) and you are trying to convert it to O(N). I don't think that is possible unless your first code block has misused the nested loops in the first place. You may want to provide the condition

Comment: *" so that I can optimise the order of complexity."* That's not how this works. If you want to iterate over these pairs of `i` and `j` then your loop is going to iterate O(n^2) times, because that's how many times you **want** the loop to iterate. There are O(n^2) pairs of `i` and `j` that you want to iterate over, so you cannot improve the time complexity by changing how you iterate over them.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure it improves readability complexity, but the following should produce the same.

```js
var i = 0, j = 1;

while (i < 9) {
  console.log(i, j);
  j += 1;
  if (j >= 10) {i += 1; j = i + 1}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `i` inside else statement or use `continue`. And declare `j` outside of the while body.

But keep in mind that this neither change "the order of complexity" nor "optimise" your code.

```js
var i = 0;
var j = 1;
while (i < 10) {

  if (j < 10) {
    if (true) {
      console.log(i, j)
    }

    j++;

  } else {
    i++;
    j = i + 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (true)`?? weird!

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust the loop lenght of `i` and check if `j` is greater or equal than `9`, then increment i and start with fresh `j`.

```js
var i = 0,
    j = 1;

while (i < 9) {
    console.log(i, j);
    // do you stuff
    if (j >= 9) j = ++i;
    j++;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```